# Diagonalize the matrix representing $A\in \operatorname{End}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & \mathrm{i}\\-\mathrm{i} & 0\end{array}\right)$ representing an endomorphism. I want to find an orthonormal basis in which this is diagonal and show that the new matrix is diagonal. I do not need analytically all steps.
I can find the eigenvectors of this matrix and show that they are orthogonal, and thus form an orthogonal basis. Normalizing the eigenvectors they then form an orthonormal basis. But how do I show that the matrix is diagonal in this basis of orthonormal vectors?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have already computed the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and an orthonormal pair of associated eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$.  We want to show that the matrix of the linear map 
$$
T(\mathbf x) = \pmatrix{1&i\\-i&0}\mathbf x
$$
relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,v_2\}$ is diagonal.  The key here is to understand the relevant definitions, i.e. what is meant by the matrix $T$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B$.  We say that $[T]_{\mathcal B} = [m_{ij}]_{i,j = 1}^2$ is the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ if for (all choices of) coefficients $a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb C$, we have
$$
T(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2) = (m_{11} a_1 + m_{12}a_2)v_1 + (m_{21}a_1 + m_{22}a_2) v_2.
$$
Because $v_1,v_2$ are eigenvectors of $T$, we can say that
$$
T(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2) = (\lambda_1 a_1 + 0\cdot a_2)v_1 + (0 \cdot a_1 + \lambda_2 a_2) v_2.
$$
In other words, the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is indeed the diagonal matrix
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2}.
$$

Comment: I think the problem is intended to be about a Hermitian matrix with a unitary change of basis. Tough to be sure as he displays no calculations... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Comment: @WillJagy I didn't notice anything missing from the problem statement.

Comment: I'm sorry I am late at responding. How come $v_1$ is only scaled by $a_1$ on the left side, but scaled by both $a_1$ and $a_2$ on the right side of the equation, and similar for $v_2$?

Comment: @JKalle are you asking about the equation with the $m_{ij}$s or the one after that?

Comment: I don't see how $v_1$ is scaled by both $a_1$ and $a_2$ on the right side in this equation $$\begin{array}{c}
T\left(a_{1} v_{1}+a_{2} v_{2}\right)=\left(m_{11} a_{1}+m_{12} a_{2}\right) v_{1} \\
+\left(m_{21} a_{1}+m_{22} a_{2}\right) v_{2}
\end{array}$$